# Optional table in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, specflow, gherkin

I have a step in SpecFlow to check whether some area is displayed (e.g. User info).

```
Then "User Info" area is displayed
```

And I would like to have optional table for this step checking some other information in the area (e.g. First name, Surname, Address...).

```
Then "User Info" area is displayed
| Surname |
| Smith   |
```

I tried to create a method with optional argument:

```
public void ThenUserInfoAreaIsDisplayed(Table table = null)
{
  ...
}
```

But I got this exception when using a step without the table:

> Parameter count mismatch! The binding method 'Example.ThenUserInfoAreaIsDisplayed()' should have 0 parameters

I also tried to overload the method:

```
public void ThenUserInfoAreaIsDisplayed()
{
  ...
}
public void ThenUserInfoAreaIsDisplayed(Table table)
{
  ...
}
```

In this case I get the following exception:

> Parameter count mismatch! The binding method 'Example.ThenUserInfoAreaIsDisplayed()' should have 1 parameters

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: can you include the `[Then("")]` attribute you have attached to your step methods

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not possible exactly as you want it. You just could add another step definition for the version with the table using a somewhat extended/modified wording:

```
Then "User Info" area is displayed
```

and

```
Then "User Info" area is displayed with this information:
| Surname |
| Smith   |
```