# Running automatic acceptance tests on Azure devops using Specflow

Tags: azure-devops, specflow

I'm trying to set up an Azure DevOps project that runs some automatic acceptance tests when a build is executed.

I have no problem running the acceptance tests on my local machine, but it seems like the tests aren't running correct when I execute the build on the DevOps platform. My Unit tests are running as expected, but the acceptance tests aren't running at all. Here is a full output log of the TestAssemblies: https://pastebin.com/ZCx1RdGp

EDIT: After removing the Runner and SpecFlow packages, I get the following output: https://pastebin.com/tTtKEcX5

The line t hat get's me the most is the lines below. It seems like it's trying to run the tests but it just doesn't do it correct:

```
2019-01-14T12:22:38.9295662Z Profile: Acceptance
2019-01-14T12:22:38.9324097Z starting test run
2019-01-14T12:22:38.9324763Z Discovering target: Default
2019-01-14T12:22:39.0023466Z test run finished
2019-01-14T12:22:39.0025670Z publishing test results
2019-01-14T12:22:39.0026124Z test results published
2019-01-14T12:22:39.0026476Z generating reports
2019-01-14T12:22:39.0026874Z creating 1 report(s)
2019-01-14T12:22:39.0027228Z generate Report ReportTemplate.cshtml
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2872092Z reports generated
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2876384Z Result: tests executed with warnings
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2876686Z   Total: 0
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2876843Z   Succeeded: 0
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2876982Z   Ignored: 0
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2877128Z   Pending: 0
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2877260Z   Skipped: 0
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2877390Z   Failed: 0
2019-01-14T12:22:40.2877504Z
```

I have included the following packages in my project:

- Nunit Package
- SpecFlow package
- NUnit3TestAdapater
- SpecRun.Runner
- SpecRun.SpecFlow

My build pipeline looks like this, I haven't done anything to any of the tasks, my guess is I'm missing some settings on the test assemblies, but I'm not sure what it  could be. As far as I could read it should be able to test this by default as long as the correct packages are in the assembly it's trying to  build:
[image]

I really hope that someone can point me in the right direction here, thanks.

**UPDATE** based on Andreas Willich answer I have done the following things

Implemented these packages into the acceptance test project
[image]

I divided my tests into two tasks, one for unit tests and another for acceptance tests. 
[image]
The unit tests runs on the default MSTest.TestAdapter, and completes successfully as before.
[image]

I'm trying to let the Acceptance test run on the TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter [image]

I was not successful in making this work. It gives me the following output: https://pastebin.com/mAR9HK2r

I'm not sure what to look for in my test assembly and my csproj file, so I didn't manage to complete these steps.

Comment: You have 2 test runners installed. NUnit 3 and the SpecFlow+Runner. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: I removed the SpecRun.Runner
SpecRun.SpecFlow packages now. I updated the question to reflect the new output log. It seems like it doesn't take the acceptance tests into account.

Answer (score 1):

First I would use two separate tasks for unit tests and acceptance tests. This makes it possible to use different test adapters for them (like NUnit and SpecFlow+Runner).

If you use SpecFlow for your acceptance tests, you need the SpecFlow package. You only have to choose which test adapter you use. See this answer which package you need depending on the test adapter you want to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990326/3155323

Additional I would restrict the assembly filter to you test assemblies. That reduces the logout put a lot, because the test adapters have to scan lesser assemblies.

As you switched to NUnit, please be sure that you have NUnit configured as unitTestProvider in your app.config and regenerated all your code-behind files.

As next step, I would open the test assembly and look if the generated tests are available. If there aren't, have a look at your csproj file, if the code-behind files are added to the Compile- ItemGroup.

Sorry that this is not a "you have forgotton to check this box" answer. When test adapters don't find any tests, there are multiple possible small reasons for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried my best to do those things you told me, but I was not successful in making it work. I updated my question based on what I tried.

Comment: In the second test task, you have to specify your test assembly with the SpecFlow scenarios. You are now only looking for tests in the test adapter itself (it's like a plugin to VSTest).

Comment: @AndreasWillich : Is this possible ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084649/optional-table-in-specflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post what I did to achieve getting SpecFlow test results to show in the Azure DevOps Builds->Tests area, however be forewarned that this is a **giant** hack.

I believe SpecFlow/NUnit tests are *supposed* to be supported just as regular NUnit tests are, and I do think it is around test adapter configuration as Andreas Willich stated, however I was neither able to get it to work for me, nor was I able to find examples of where anyone has gotten this to work through normal pipeline configuration. SpecFlow+ may also have ways of working, but I don't use the plus version. If/when I can learn the proper way to do this, I'll stop using the below.

1. Create a simple process to write SpecFlow test name and test result values to disc in CSV format. I did this because I wanted to separate feature testing solutions from any other logic going on with this hack. This process should be as simple as using an [AfterScenario] hook step to pull the Scenario title and result values from Scenario.Context - or wherever you can get them - and writing them to a text file in comma-separated value format.
2. Integrate that CSV result logging process into the "SpecFlow" project that contains tests for which you want results to show in Azure DevOps.

The CSV should look something like this:

```
DemoScenario_01 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, Pass
DemoScenario_02 Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore, Pass
DemoScenario_03 Magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam quis, Pass
DemoScenario_04 Nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip, Pass
DemoScenario_05 Ex ea commodo consequat Duis aute irure dolor in, Pass
DemoScenario_06 Reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu, Pass
DemoScenario_07 Fugiat nulla pariatur Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat, Pass
DemoScenario_08 Non proident sunt in culpa qui officia semper, Pass
DemoScenario_09 Deserunt mollit anim id est laborum arcu semper, Pass
DemoScenario_10 Orci a scelerisque purus semper eget Ornare arcu dui vivamus, Pass
```

3. Create a separate simple "dummy" project containing only a single class having one working NUnit "test" method that does nothing but Assert.Pass(). This project will need the NUnit and NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet packages installed.

The class should look something like this:

```
    namespace DemoNunit
    {
        public class Tests
        {
            [Test]
            public static void DemoTest005()
            {
                Assert.Pass();
            }
        }
    }
```

4. Create an Azure DevOps Git Code Repository for this "dummy" project's solution and push it to the repo.
5. Create a new Azure Pipeline configured for CI builds which will auto-trigger when commits to the "dummy" NUnit project are pushed to its the repo. Configure the pipeline to have a Visual Studio Test step called "SpecFlow Tests" which looks for the dll containing that single NUnit test. Name this pipeline per your "SpecFlow" project or the functionality it tests, as this pipeline will actually end up showing those results in the Builds->Tests area.
6. In a new and separate "convert" project, create a process which will read the simple CSV output result file from your "SpecFlow" project, and will write a new .cs file over the existing one in the "dummy" project that houses the NUnit test.

The single NUnit test method in the "dummy" project will now be replaced with multiple methods, one for each result that was logged in the CSV. These methods will be named as guids minus any dashes, and prefixed with a letter to make them valid C# method names. The goal is just to have non-repeating method names. The actual SpecFlow test scenario names will be stored in the NUnit TestCase TestName attributes. Assert.Pass() or Assert.Fail() will be used per the associated result values read from the CSV file. Compile this "convert" project into an exe.

I've left out the code for reading the CSV results...

```
    namespace CreateCsFile
    {
        public static class CsFile
        {
            public static string OpenClass = 
                "using NUnit.Framework;" +
                "namespace DemoNunit" +
                "{" +
                "    public class Tests" +
                "    {";
            public static string CloseClass =
                "    }" +
                "}";
            public static string TestMethod =
                "        [Test, TestCase(TestName = \"UniqueNameAttribute\")]" +
                "        public static void MethodName()" +
                "        {" +
                "            Assert.Result();" +
                "        }";
            public static void LogListOfResults(
                List<Test> resultsList)
            {
                Log.CsharpFile(OpenClass);
                foreach (var result in resultsList)
                {
                    Outcome.IsValid(result.Result);
                    var testMethod =
                        TestMethod.Replace(
                                "UniqueNameAttribute",
                                result.Name).
                            Replace(
                                "Result",
                                result.Result).
                            Replace("MethodName",
                                "a" + Guid.NewGuid().
                                    ToString().
                                    Replace("-",""));
                    Log.CsharpFile(testMethod);
                }
                Log.CsharpFile(CloseClass);
            }

            public static void ConvertCsvResultsToNunitResults()
            {
                LogListOfResults(
                    ParseCsv.ResultsSheet());
            }
        }
    }
```

Log class...

```
namespace CreateCsFile
{
    public class Log
    {
        public static string WasFileRemoved
            = "";
        public static string CsFileToggle
            = "True";
        public static string CsFile
            = "C:\\Projects\\DemoNunit\\Tests.cs";
        public static void CsharpFile(
            string nunitData)
        {
            if (CsFileToggle.ToUpper()
                == "TRUE")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(
                    WasFileRemoved))
                {
                    RemoveExistingCsFile();
                }
                var log = !File.Exists(CsFile) ?
                    new StreamWriter(CsFile) :
                    File.AppendText(CsFile);
                log.WriteLine(nunitData);
                log.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void RemoveExistingCsFile()
        {
            if (CsFileToggle.ToUpper()
                == "TRUE")
            {
                WasFileRemoved = "True";
                try
                {
                    var fileInfo = 
                        new FileInfo(CsFile);
                    fileInfo.Attributes =
                        FileAttributes.Normal;
                    File.Delete(fileInfo.FullName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        @"Unable to delete existing csharp file...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ugly Output:

```
namespace DemoNunit{    public class Tests    {
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_01 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit")]        public static void aa5f7fd239d6a40878780bc6c81f3a18b()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_02 Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore")]        public static void aa9882fa95b17499eb9386b20a7ff303d()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_03 Magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam quis")]        public static void a440c25f8c3c24e92ad90224da56bafda()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_04 Nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip")]        public static void ab2c3cc6997df4a42b0992128f63358f7()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_05 Ex ea commodo consequat Duis aute irure dolor in")]        public static void a2c9f744dcd2c42c99cb6e288cf09fc78()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_06 Reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu")]        public static void a294422ae029049f9ac4be6f9bb4529cc()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_07 Fugiat nulla pariatur Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat")]        public static void aa2dcdf889ffe4e46b57a73882d6f1a68()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_08 Non proident sunt in culpa qui officia semper")]        public static void a891c43376a5049f89ad75b70fa0a543f()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_09 Deserunt mollit anim id est laborum arcu semper")]        public static void aa8da317895214abc966c229c832c162f()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
        [Test, TestCase(TestName = "DemoScenario_10 Orci a scelerisque purus semper eget Ornare arcu dui vivamus")]        public static void aa9accb0c9c1b4918b76bc75ff2f2e835()        {            Assert. Pass();        }
    }}
```

Now perform these steps:

- execute your "SpecFlow" project's tests via command line using the
  NUnit console TestRunner (it should be configured to drop the CSV
  output to some place like c:\Temp)
- execute your "convert" project which should be configured to read the
  CSV in c:\Temp and update the .cs file in the "dummy" project
  wherever its cloned repo exists on disc
- via command line arguments, have git commit and push to the repo the
  change that the "convert" exe made to the "dummy" project's .cs file

The Azure Pipeline will now build and show the results from the "SpecFlow" project's test executions as "SpecFlow Tests" using the names and results that it stored in the CSV (mine have some demo Ids as well)
[image]

There are different ways this can be set up; one way is:

- put your "SpecFlow" project into a git repo and create a CI pipeline
  for it
- add a build step set to execute the tests via command line
- add a step to call the "convert" exe which has been placed into a
  fixed location on the build box and updates the "dummy" project's file where it is housed in a separate VM in a shared location
- add a step to push the latest update to the "dummy" project to the git repo

This pipeline would now auto-trigger upon commits pushed to its repo, and the process would automatically convert the SpecFlow results to NUnit results, trigger the secondary pipeline, and show the SpecFlow results in the Builds->Tests area of that second pipleine. The first pipeline would show no results, you would always look at the second pipeline to see them.

To support more/other "SpecFlow" projects in this way...they could probably all share the "convert" piece, but it would need to be improved to have the ability to have passed into it the location of the .cs file it was updating. Then you could create separate "dummy" projects (and of course associated repos/pipelines) for each "SpecFlow" project you wanted to see results for in this fashion. I haven't gotten this far yet as I'm only doing this for a single project currently.